# How to automatically generate straight lines with a specific angle from points using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have multiple points and the distance of each points is nearly 2 meters. However, there are some points which has the distance much smaller than 2 meters.

How can I generate  straight lines with 120 degrees (or mostly straight, the blue colour lines on the picture) from the points which has distance approximately 2 meters. The points which cannot generate straight lines will have distance with other much less than or larger than 2m should be removed (points with blue cross on the picture) using arcpy script as I have thousand points?

[image]

Comment: How would you identify the trees you want to keep? That is by far the most difficult part. If you were to create a line feature class then draw lines through the polygons you want to keep you can use select by location https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-location.htm, select by attributes (switch selection) https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-attribute.htm you could then delete features https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/delete-features.htm

Comment: When you say, " the distance of each tree should be 2 meters," I assume you mean the tree crown should be at least 2 meters in diameter, which can be used with a couple assumptions to set a minimum polygon size for the trees you want to keep.  With some trial and error, you should be able to find criteria that work fairly well.

Comment: @ Michael Stimson: Thank you for your advice. I edit my question to clarify my purpose.

Comment: Does each point have any attributes associated with it? and if so what are they?

Comment: @Clubdebambos: Each point only have the x and y coordinates associated with it.

Comment: How good is your python?  I created [this tool](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=2b0c54fe415641e7af8490c4ba7d4bcf) a few years ago, should work in ArcMap. If you want to use it in Arcpro the code needs updating as it is using an older version of python. If this tool is what you need you could try tweaking the code or get back to me and I can update it, but you will have to wait until next week.

Comment: @Hornbydd: Thank you for your great suggestion. I will run the tool in arcmap and get back to you.

Comment: @Hornbydd: I can run your tool but it does not do my task as expected.